# Rhyming riddle - you'll drown in me

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> You'll drown in me
>   An unfathomable sea
>   You cannot flee
>   Hard to break free
>   You won't see sense
>   Panic commence
>   The brain's defense
>   At your expense
>   Scared my prey
>   You're mine to play
>   Lead you astray
>   Blocked airway
>   You must comply
>   Mouth goes dry
>   Have a pry
>   At what am I?

Comment: "Facebook" fits almost all the clues...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> Fear

Explanation:

You'll drown in me

> You can "drown" in fear when it overwhelms you.

An unfathomable sea

> Fear doesn't always seem make rational sense (eg. some phobias).

You cannot flee
Hard to break free
You won't see sense

> As said above, fear can seem to be irrational. It can overwhelm you meaning that it is hard to overcome it.

Panic commence
The brains defense
At your expense

> Once you see something you're afraid of, you'll start to panic. I cannot be sure about "brain's defence", although maybe panic is indeed the brain's way to deal with fear. If it is, it certainly will be at your expense.

Scared my prey
Your mine to play

> Predators strike fear into their prey. Eg. cats playing with their food before they're eaten (like little birds :/).

Lead you astray

> As said above, fear can be irrational, and this will lead you astray as things start to go out of proportion. (eg. something small like a wasp can cause a large panic).

Blocked airway

> It can be hard to breathe when in panic/fear.

You must comply

> Hard not to give in to your instincts and run, so you must comply.

Mouth goes dry

> Happens during fear.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly totally off base, but

> Asthma

You'll drown in me
An unfathomable sea
You cannot flee
Hard to break free

> Just as with drowning, asthma deprives the victim of oxygen. It is unfathomable because it is like drowning in a sea that isn't there. And you can't run away. There is no shoreline, no lifesaver. Without medication, it can be very hard to escape.

You won't see sense
Panic commence
The brains defense
At your expense

> It is very frightening when you can't breathe. The body's natural defense is to pump adrenaline into your system, but this may not help. It may just leave you gasping harder for air.

Scared my prey
Your mine to play
Lead you astray
Blocked airway

> When the airway is blocked by swelling and fear sets in, people may make irrational decisions (Lead you astray). They may just have to wait for the attack to pass (mine to play)

You must comply
Mouth goes dry
Have a pry
At what am I?

> There is no cure for asthma although the symptoms can be treated, and a dry mouth is a common symptom of the fear that sets in during an attack.